# ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

Basically, I am trying to deploy cloud functions using my cloudbuild.yaml file:

Cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: 'node:10.10.0'
  id: installing_npm
  args: ['npm', 'install']
  dir: 'API/groups'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  id: deploy
  args: [
          'functions', 'deploy', 'groups', 
          '--region=us-central1',
          '--source=https://source.cloud.google.com/$PROJECT_ID/bitbucket_zebraema_/+/LCM-97_groups_API_test:API/groups', 
          '--trigger-http', 
          '--runtime=nodejs8', 
          '--entry-point=App', 
          '--allow-unauthenticated',
          '--service-account=xaxaxax@appspot.gserviceaccount.com'
        ]
  dir: 'API/groups'
```

Below is the error:

```
Step #0 - "installing_npm": npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
Step #0 - "installing_npm": 
Step #0 - "installing_npm": added 448 packages from 284 contributors and audited 449 packages in 9.697s
Step #0 - "installing_npm": found 5 low severity vulnerabilities
Step #0 - "installing_npm":   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Finished Step #0 - "installing_npm"
Starting Step #1 - "deploy"
Step #1 - "deploy": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Step #1 - "deploy": ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden], message=[Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.get' denied on resource 'projects/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/locations/us-central1/functions/groups' (or resource may not exist).]
Finished Step #1 - "deploy"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Edit:
I have added Cloud functions Developer, Cloud functions Admin, Cloud Functions Service Agent and Service account user roles to my cloud build service account.

Cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
    - name: 'node:10.10.0'
      id: installing_npm
      args: ['npm', 'install']
      dir: 'API/groups'
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
      id: deploy
      args: [
              'functions', 'deploy', 'groups', 
              '--region=us-central1',
              '--source=https://source.cloud.google.com/$PROJECT_ID/bitbucket_zebraema_/+/LCM-97_groups_API_test:API/groups', 
              '--trigger-http', 
              '--runtime=nodejs8', 
              '--entry-point=App', 
              '--allow-unauthenticated',
              '--service-account=$PROJECT_ID@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com'
            ]
      dir: 'API/groups'
```

Below logs:

```
Step #0 - "installing_npm":   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Finished Step #0 - "installing_npm"
Starting Step #1 - "deploy"
Step #1 - "deploy": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Step #1 - "deploy": ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[400], code=[Bad Request], message=[The request has errors
Step #1 - "deploy": Problems:
Step #1 - "deploy": source_repository_url:
Step #1 - "deploy": Source repository URL is invalid https://source.cloud.google.com/xyxyxyxyx/bitbucket_zebraema/LCM-97_groups_API_test/API/groups/src does not match the expected pattern, which is https://source.developers.google.com/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/repos/{REPOSITORY_ID}/revisions/{REVISION_ID}/paths/{PATH} or https://source.developers.google.com/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/repos/{REPOSITORY_ID}/moveable-aliases/{BRANCH_ID}/paths/{PATH} or https://source.developers.google.com/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/repos/{REPOSITORY_ID}/fixed-aliases/{TAG_ID}/paths/{PATH}. Note that PROJECT_ID, REPOSITORY_ID, REVISION_ID, BRANCH_ID, and TAG_ID can not contain '/'. PATH may contain '/'.
Step #1 - "deploy": ]
Finished Step #1 - "deploy"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Here, I have mirrored my `bitbucket` repository into my `google cloud source repository`. What is the correct way to write `source_repository_url`?

Comment: try again adding Cloud Functions Developer role to your Cloud Build service account

Comment: I have added `Cloud functions Developer`, `Cloud functions Admin`, `Cloud Functions Service Agent` and `Service account user` roles to my cloud build service account but still getting the same error.

Comment: There is a confirmed issue with deployments of Cloud Functions and App Engine in us-central1, you may be affected by this. [More info here](https://status.cloud.google.com/)

Comment: @Pritish did you find the error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely reason is `Cloud Functions Developer` role not being enabled for the `Cloud Build` service.

1. Navigate to Cloud Build > Settings
2. Enable Cloud Functions Developer Role

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message `Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.get' denied`.

Maybe you can try to grant this permission to the cloudbuild default service account.

cloudbuild default service account is look like `YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: I added `Cloud functions Admin` role but still getting the same error.

Comment: you are correct. Modified my cloudbuild service account. I have updated my question. have a look at my `Edit` section.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to grant the "Project Editor" role to your service account.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the GCP console > Menu > IAM & Admin > IAM > Edit [@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com] and grant these three access mentioned in the picture below.

[image: cloudbuild service account access]